# Redirect response into a dynamic url

Tags: node.js, express

I am using node js with:

- express framework
- hbs framework
- mongodb

My task is to redirect my response to a url with a format `/users/:name/course/:courseId`.

After running the code with the parameters name=James and courseId=1234, I get `/users/James/course/1234` in the browser url. However, I am not able to post to `/users/James/course/1234`.

Edit: the data is being successfully posted, but I am getting a message Cannot GET /users/James/course/1234.

I have the following code:

app.js:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('form.hbs')
})

app.post('/saveUsers', [
    // firstname must contain letters only
    check('firstname', 'First name should contain only letters').isAlpha(),
    // email must be in a email format
    check('email', 'Email field must be in a email format').isEmail(),
    // courseId must be numerical and exactly 4 digits
    check('courseId', 'course ID should contain only numbers').isNumeric(),
    check('courseId', 'course ID should be exactly 4 digits').isLength({ min: 4, max: 4 })
], (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req)
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array(), data:req.body})
    }
    var db = utils.getDb()
    db.collection('users').insertOne({
        name: req.body.firstname,
        email: req.body.email,
        courseId: req.body.courseId
    }, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            Response.send('Unable to insert a student')
        }
        console.log(result.ops)
        nameUrl = result.ops[0].name
        courseIdUrl = result.ops[0].courseId
        res.redirect(`/users/${nameUrl}/course/${courseIdUrl}`)
    })
})

app.post(`/users/${nameUrl}/course/${courseIdUrl}`, (req, res) => {
    res.json(result.ops)
})
```

form.hbs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <p>Enter your name, email and course ID:</p>
        <form action="/saveUsers" method="POST" id="myForm">
            <input type="text" placeholder="firstname" name="firstname">
            <input type="email" placeholder="email" name="email">
            <input type="text" placeholder="courseId" name="courseId">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using template literal string interpolation where you should be using the Express syntax for route parameters. See the "route parameters" section in the [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).

Instead of:

```
app.post(`/users/${nameUrl}/course/${courseIdUrl}`, (req, res) => {
    res.json(result.ops)
})
```

Try:

```
app.post(`/users/:name/course/:courseId`, (req, res) => {
    res.json(result.ops)
})
```

Comment: still getting the same message, Cannot GET /users/James/course/1234.

Comment: you have to set up a route using `app.get(`/users/:name/course/:courseId`` then. Right now you just have `app.post(`/users/:name/course/:courseId``